# Using multiple SQL statements inside one another

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: user, vote and song.

Song contains song details
Vote contains the song id, the user who voted and the vote value
user contains user details

When a user votes on a song, their vote is stored. Either a 1 or a 0. Every song has a genre which is recognised per vote.

What I am trying to do is something like this...

```
Pop    1
Rock   3
Reggie 4

Vote percent is the total amount of 1s received so 1, 3, 4. 
These as a % is my aim so Reggie would be 50%. (8/4) and so on...
I then want to use this list of prefered genres to pick songs based on the % values.
```

So if there are any Reggie songs this would be returned first in a list.

```
SELECT s.* FROM song s
WHERE (
SELECT 100.00 * SUM(CASE WHEN vote = '1' THEN 1 WHEN vote = '2' THEN 0.5
                         ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(v.vote) AS votePercent 
                         FROM song s 
                         LEFT JOIN collaborate c 
                         ON s.song_id = c.song_id 
                         LEFT JOIN voting v 
                         ON s.song_id = v.song_id
                         WHERE v.user_id = 'user0d1c-944f-4fff-b819-16869750f2d4'
                         ) 
                          GROUP BY s.genre;
```

What I have tried so far seems off as the percent value comes out as 100% and 50% for genres instead of a percentage of total votes.

Also my current query would almost definately return songs that have already been voted on.

Have I gone in a wrong direction, or does this hold some promise for what I hope to achieve?

Comment: This is doable.  Can you edit the post to list the table structures (ie data types)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your `group by`, when you get `COUNT(v.vote)` it's the grouped count, not the total count.

try this:

```
SELECT s.* FROM song s
WHERE (
SELECT 100.00 * SUM(CASE WHEN vote = '1' THEN 1 WHEN vote = '2' THEN 0.5
                         ELSE 0 END) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voting) AS votePercent 
                         FROM song s 
                         LEFT JOIN collaborate c 
                         ON s.song_id = c.song_id 
                         LEFT JOIN voting v 
                         ON s.song_id = v.song_id
                         WHERE v.user_id = 'user0d1c-944f-4fff-b819-16869750f2d4'
                         ) 
                         GROUP BY s.genre;
```

The problem that then might arise is that both count and your sum are integers, so mysql might be dropping the decimal values from your results.

To fix this we can cast the SUM as a decimal :

```
SELECT s.* FROM song s
WHERE (
SELECT 100.00 * CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN vote = '1' THEN 1 WHEN vote = '2' THEN 0.5
                         ELSE 0 END) as DECIMAL(10,2) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voting) AS votePercent 
                         FROM song s 
                         LEFT JOIN collaborate c 
                         ON s.song_id = c.song_id 
                         LEFT JOIN voting v 
                         ON s.song_id = v.song_id
                         WHERE v.user_id = 'user0d1c-944f-4fff-b819-16869750f2d4'
                         ) 
                         GROUP BY s.genre;
```

This is untested, but I think it might point you in the right direction.